# Converting unprintable characters to printable characters in Java using ISO8859_15_FDIS

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have the following code :

```
System.out.println(new String("–’".getBytes("ISO8859_15_FDIS")));
```

The two characters in the first String are:

- – (`96` in hex)
- ’ (`92` in hex)

The output of the code is:

```
??
```

Which is to be expected as [the code page for ISO8859_15_FDIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) shows that the two characters above are not in the printable part of the table.

What I would like to get is an acceptable mapping:

```
-'
```

(ie `2D` and `27` in ISO8859_15_FDIS)

Is there a way to perform this conversion within the standard Java API, or am I just going to have to store some kind of explicit mapping (`Map<Character,Character>`) between the actual value and the wanted value?

For a bit of context, we have a Sybase database that is using this character set, and when users paste those characters into text areas on the fronting web app, they end up as question marks in the database.

Comment: Those two characters are actually 0x2013 and 0x2019, the values you give are probably their encoding in the windows 1252 codepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code like this is never correct:

```
new String(string1.getBytes(ENC_1), ENC_2);
```

The above code is always a transcoding bug.

The correct way to transcode these code points from windows-1252 to ISO8859_15_FDIS is as follows:

```
byte[] windows1252 = { (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0x92 };
String utf16 = new String(windows1252, Charset.forName("windows-1252"));
byte[] iso8859_15_FDIS = utf16.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO8859_15_FDIS"));
```

Java chars are always implicitly UTF-16 and all other encodings should be represented using byte arrays.

However, ISO-8859-15 does not support the two code points (U+2013 and U+2019) so this will be a lossy process.  The values you are expecting (U+002D and U+0027) have identical byte values in both encodings.

These are just completely different code points and you will have to maintain some form of normalization routine to map characters that have visually similar graphemes.